# How to tab through a element in HTML, if it is disabled

Tags: html, accessibility, tabindex, disabled-input

I am working on a project to make a site accessible for blind users.
I have a input box which is disabled by default and act as a label.
But I am not able to access that using TAB key while tabbing through the site.

I have tried:-

```
tabindex="0"
```

which will make that element accessible using keyboard(Tab key).

I know that if the input box contains

```
disabled="true"
```

then

```
tabindex="0"
```

But that doesn't work either.

Is there any other way to make it accessible using keyboard only, so that the screen reader will read the data inside the disabled input box for the blind user?

Comment: could you provide a JSFiddle ?

Comment: Any specific reason you wanna tab over a disabled true input?

Comment: "that the screen reader will read the data inside the disabled input box for the blind user" — Disabled inputs are not designed for displaying output. The semantics mean "This is not relevant". If you're trying to present information, don't use a disabled input.

Comment: @AngularHarsh i want to tab through a disabled item so that screen reader can read the data inside it to the blind user.

Comment: @Quentin this is the requirement, is there any way to tab through a disabled input box.

Comment: It's a bad requirement. Push back on it.

Comment: @Quentin So you are saying there is no way to achieve it?

Comment: Nope. As Quentin said, it is a bad requirement. If it is disabled then it should be a span not an input box. Even with readonly=true, it will not tab over it.

Comment: "I have a input box which is disabled by default and act as a **label**". Sounds like you should be using a `label` tag instead.

Answer (score 0):

How about use `readonly` instead of `disabled`?  That will still allow the `<input>` to be in the tab order but the user can't modify it.  A screen reader will read the contents of the `<input>` field and will additionally say "read only".